# Alter table modify <column> does not work in Hsqldb with Oracle syntax

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hsqldb, flyway

The `Flyway` migrations in my `Java` project need to be able to run both in `Oracle` and in in-memory `Hsqldb`. Since I have `Oracle`, I run "`SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX ORA TRUE`" in my `Hsqldb`. That fixes some issues, but I'm short on ideas when it comes to changing storage size of a column.

- Works in `Oracle`, not in `Hsqldb`: "`alter table foo modify mycol varchar2(25)`"
- Works in `Hsqldb`, not in `Oracle`: "`alter table foo alter column mycol varchar2(25)`"

How can I find a syntax that both can agree on...?

Comment: Sorry but the syntax is specific to the database. It is the same thing for types.Sometimes, you are lucky : they may be the same for some things but it is not the general case. Enabling the oracle syntax helps but cannot address all the differences. Since you use Hsqldb with a in-memory databse, it should not be a problem since the base is recreated at each start of the application. Are you sure to use a in-memory database ? Don't you use a persistent file for your Hsqldb database ?

Comment: I want a list of migration scripts that works both in Oracle and in in-mem hsqldb for auto-testing. 
Because of how Flyway works, when migrating on a persistent DB it's easier to add an "alter table" instead of changing the existing "create table". "Create table" works fine in both hsqldb and Oracle.
But since I can't find a query that works both with hsqldb and Oracle, I may have to add an alternative SQL for each DB system.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to resurrect an old thread, but I happened upon it and thought I'd answer.

I'm in the same predicament.  I use HSQLDB for local development and Oracle for deployed apps.  I also use Flyway for my migrations.  I run Flyway as part of Maven so that the guys who can touch production don't have to install a lot manually.  If they have Java and Maven, then I can do the rest.

In my `src/main/resources`, I created a `migrations` directory.  Inside that, I created `common`, `oracle` and `hsqldb` directories.  Most of my scripts go in `common` and the vendor-specific ones go in their own.  However, the numbering scheme is constant across all of them.  In other words, I never reuse a version number.  I like this approach because if one day we switch to another vendor (fingers crossed for PostgreSQL), then I can hopefully just make another directory, and put the syntax-specific stuff for it there.

When it's time to run Flyway for hsqldb, it looks like this:

```sh
mvn flyway:migrate \
-Dflyway.locations=migrations/common,migrations/hsqldb \
-Dflyway.url="${DB_URL}"
```

When it's time to run it against deployed environments (Oracle), it looks like this:

```sh
mvn flyway:migrate \
-Dflyway.locations=migrations/common,migrations/oracle \
-Dflyway.url="${DB_URL}" \
-Dflyway.user="${DB_USERNAME}" \
-Dflyway.password="${DB_PASSWORD}"
```

The only substantial difference is the values of the two locations for Flyway migration scripts.  One uses hsqldb and the other uses oracle.

I tried to find a way to avoid this, but as the app grew, altering a table was inevitable.  Creating views required specialized syntax.  I also had to grant access to other users in Oracle only.